# Widget animation in CustomTkinter Python

Tags: tkinter, animation, widget

I want to make 4 (main) buttons, when clicked, they will pop up 3 more (local) buttons and move the rest of the main buttons from the bottom, and when you click on another or one that is already open, close the open button and open on the one you clicked, and so with all 4 buttons

I tried to do with lists and change the place configuration. It seems that everything works, albeit on crutches, but when the button shifts the other buttons, then at the time of the animation, artifacts from the outline of the bottom buttons appear.

Maybe there is a link to the gidhub, or someone will write a simple example?

Comment: Description is not clear!

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: хахах Русс, так да уж

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.